# return number of zeros in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, zero

How do you return the number of zeros in an array in JavaScript?

For example this array has numbers [ 2, 3, 0 , 9, 0] and it should output to 2 zeros.

Thanks for responding! I'm still a newbie at JavaScript.

Comment: Keep searching here www.google.com

Comment: [....].filter(function(a){return a===0}).length

Comment: No this is not a school assignment.

Comment: [0,3,3,0,43,0].filter(/./.test, /^0$/).length

Comment: [0,3,3,0,43,0].filter(Object.is.bind(Object,0)).length

Comment: [0,3,3,0,43,0].sort().lastIndexOf(0)+1 (+nums only)

Comment: "".match.call([0,3,3,0,43,0], /\b0,|(,0$)?/g).filter(String).length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this there could be better solutions also.

```
var arr =  [2, 3, 0 , 9, 0];
var zeros = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el == 0;
});

console.log(zeros.length)
```